# I am trying to integrate scrum 2b in my bitnami redmine stack.Please provide some guidelines?

Tags: plugins, redmine, bitnami

First off I am totally new to rails. So far, all that I have done is that I copied a scrum 2b plugin inside a folder named installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins. Now according to the official documentation ([Offical scrum2b doc](https://github.com/scrum2b/scrum2b/wiki/Installation-Guide)) I need to run the following command

```
bundle install
```

however according to this documentation ([Bitnami documentation](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Redmine)) I am supposed to run the following command

```
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite
```

However this version of my redmine uses mysql database. So am I supposed to run bundle install only? or bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite? Well I would be really grateful if someone would point some resources that clearly states what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite
```

is better for you. It is more "accurate" for your environment.

Option `without` means that you are going to exclude some gems during the installation. If you look at Redmine [Gemfile](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.4-stable/Gemfile) you can find `group` blocks. It skips the blocks listed after the `without` parameter

`development`/`test` - skip gems needed only in development/test environment
`postgresql`/`sqlite` - skip gems for some DBs (you use MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this here because I can't comment yet. Don't try to use any Scrum plugins on Redmine. The best way to go is to handle the situation yourself and implement your own way of doing Scrum on Redmine. Nearly all of the Scrum plugins for Redmine do work with only one layer of trackers (the default "Tasks") which isn't suitable for Scrum. You won't have any Scrum boards but you could always have reports on PBI (Product Backlog Items), SBI (Sprint Backlog Items), Work Item trackers with any combination of filters to achieve a Scrum Board like reporting tool.

You should create your own trackers:

a- to separate the business layer (Product Owner, Stakeholders in Scrum etc) from the devteam (Team and Scrum Master)

b- to reflect the "PBI / SBI / Work Item" layers

PBI's don't have "completion time estimations", "assignees" etc whilst being the upper layer (container) of SBI's and Work Items which do have these fields.

Don't forget that trackers are just like tags for actions and that you can use different data fields for different trackers.